# Matrix reorganization

Tags: r

I have a matrix of 6 rows and a vector of length 6 which I want to use to reorganize my Matrix.

The first row of my new matrix should contain the row in position of the value of the first number of my vector.

The second row of my new matrix should contain the row in position of the value of the second number of my vector.

Here is an example:

```
> Matrix <- matrix(rnorm(30),nrow=6,ncol=5)
> Vector <- c(1,3,6,2,4,5)
```

The actual first row will after the operation be at the first row position.
The actual second row will, after the operation be at the third row position.
The actual third row will, after the operation be at the sixth row position.
and so on....

I hope I'm clear enough in my explanations !

In order to make my question clearer I did this edit

**Edit:**

```
> Matrix=matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),nrow=3,ncol=3,byrow=T)
> Matrix

        [,1][,2][,3]
    [1,] 1    2   3
    [2,] 4    5   6  
    [3,] 7    8   9

> Vector=c(2,3,1)
```

I want to reorganisze the rows in order to obtain this:

```
> NewMatrix=matrix(c(4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3),byrow=T)
> NewMatrix

        [,1][,2][,3]
    [1,] 4    5   6
    [2,] 7    8   9 
    [3,] 1    2   3
```

the 2nd row is now in the 1st position, the 3rd row is now at the 2nd position and the 1st row is now at the 3rd position.

Comment: Can you make this clearer? Maybe just explicitly write out an example with for a 3x3 system? It sounds like you are wanting to do something standard but don't yet know what the name for it is ... but I can't quite guess yet what you are trying to do. One of the trickiest parts of learning math is figuring out how to describe things to other people! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use vector indexing:

```
Matrix[Vector,]
```

To see what is happening, better to use  a different `Matrix`:

```
Matrix=matrix(1:30, nrow=6)
Matrix
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
## [1,]    1    7   13   19   25
## [2,]    2    8   14   20   26
## [3,]    3    9   15   21   27
## [4,]    4   10   16   22   28
## [5,]    5   11   17   23   29
## [6,]    6   12   18   24   30
Matrix[Vector,]
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
## [1,]    1    7   13   19   25
## [2,]    3    9   15   21   27
## [3,]    6   12   18   24   30
## [4,]    2    8   14   20   26
## [5,]    4   10   16   22   28
## [6,]    5   11   17   23   29
```